# How do I name my build?

Tags: c, auto-increment, revision

What is the proper way to name my revisions?

```
v1.0.3.20 Alpha
```

or

```
Alpha v1.0.3.20
```

Comment: The latter is much more common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really any "proper" way. While most people use the dot pattern "x.x.x", it isn't necessarily the proper way to do it. Likewise with your question, it is up to you.

I would suppose that the former is more natural to say, and I would prefer it, but it doesn't really matter either way.

Comment: Thank you, I guess it's own personal preference

Answer (score 0):

You have two pieces of information there: version number and release state/quality.  The two might be tied together, but don't have to be.  For example, you could have multiple "releases" for a single version number: v1.1-alpha, v1.1-beta, v1.1-final, and so forth; or you could break those down into individual numbers: v1.0.1-alpha, v1.0.2-beta, v1.1.0-final; or something entirely different!

This is really a question of branding more than anything; due to the wide interpretation of version info across different products, you already have to know how each different product uses them to make sense of it.  Of course, if you're contributing to, working with, or emulating another project: do what they do.  It'll be simpler and lead to less confusion.

As used in my examples, I'd prefer "n.n...-quality", but it's only syntax.